# ROS2 topic list does not show all available topics running on network

Tags: ros2

I am working with ROS2, I got the situation that '**ros2 topic list**' doesn't show all topics on the ros2 network.

The above command only showed :

[image]

I think that there's certain mismatch in configuration with **DDS** distros. I studied around Internet and got [Cyclone DDS](https://dds-demonstrators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Teams/1.Hurricane/setupCycloneDDS.html) background supports ROS2 distribution. Also, the [run-time configuration](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds#run-time-configuration) of Cyclone DDS is via **CYCLONEDDS_URI** environmental export.

I expect that the 'ros2 topic list' shall show all my available topics (plus 2 topics */parameter_events* and */rosout*).

Anybody runs into the same issue to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of the lack of //CycloneDDS/Domain/Discovery ([Discovery](https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/blob/master/docs/manual/options.md#cycloneddsdomaindiscovery) tag). The **Discovery** element allows specifying various parameters related to the discovery of peers.

The issue can be resolved by adding the **<Discovery>...</Discovery>** tag as below:

[image]

Comment: thank you. I switched the fastrtps after saw your question then I can see the device. Can you tell me how to add this tag? where is the related file?